# Docusign document retrieve using Docusign-connect

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Docusign-Connet to get the notifications form docusign. In docusign api there is a line

> "It can also be used to transport the completed documents back to your app or website and to retrieve any form field data entered by your recipients"

but in payload I am getting only document names?.

Comment: There are many triggered events from connect, which event trigger are you viewing the payload from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And please check/accept the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the connect messages to include the envelopes' documents or fields, check the boxes in the Connection Subscription screen (shown below from the New DocuSign Experience Admin tool).

Or set the fields `includeDocumentFields` and/or `includeDocuments` to `true` in your call to [**ConnectConfigurations: create**](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectConfigurations/create/)

[image]

Comment: Even though i selected those fields i am getting the PdfBytes instead of Document?

Comment: PdfBytes are your documents in pdf format. DocuSign converts all source documents to PDF documents for signing. The originals are not available.

Comment: Thanks Larry, If i uploaded a file of 5mb i am not getting the payload at a single time, its updating the payload. It has taken 3 minutes to get all payload so how can i handle it?

Comment: @J.Ravindra  -- I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Please start a new question so you can include full details of what is happening and your question. And please "check" / "select" this answer if it is the best one for your question.

Answer (score 2):

What i've done in the past is, get the document statuses from DocuSignConnect when things change. Then call `EnvelopesApi.GetDocument` endpoint with `DocumentStatuses.DocumentStatus.ID` and the envelope ID to retrieve the document.

In my implementation, we only download the document if the entire envelope is complete. This way, the DocuSignConnect payload is not big as well.

Btw, my implementation is in `.net` using their `2.1.9.0` library.
Good luck!

Comment: That is the right approach because DocuSign does not recommend to download documetns via webhook, it degrades performance heavily and you gonna lose so many envelopes later